# Haskell, create stack or cabal file from source directory

Tags: stack, cabal

In Haskell: Given an existing  directory tree (with sub-directors) of source files.

Is there a way to get a .cabal or .stack file, created automatically, with all the necessary dependents (references to the import files that are embedded inside the source file) embedded in the command file,with no need to manualy editing the command file.

In other words, get a command file that I will be able to run "straight out of the box" without the regular methods of stack new/stack build etc,commands?

Answer (score 0):

`cabal init` will create a file that lists all the modules in your sourcedir for you. But you will still need to provide the package dependencies yourself. This is because a module `Foo.Bar.Baz` may come from multiple packages -- hence the package you *intend* to import must be explicitly specified.